# При отправке запроса пишет что гилдии не существует

Tags: python, логирование, fastapi

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import multiprocessing
import logging

from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, HTTPException
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True

app = FastAPI()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    logger.info(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.guild.id}')

@app.get('/get_channel_counts/')
async def get_channel_info(
    guild_id: int = Query(..., description='guild_id'),
    channel_ids: str = Query(..., description='channel_ids')
):
    print(guild_id)
    print(channel_ids)
    
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    print(guild)
    channel_counts = {}

    if guild is not None:
        for voice_channel in guild.voice_channels:
            if str(voice_channel.id) in channel_ids:
                channel_counts[voice_channel.name] = len(voice_channel.members)

        return {"status": "success", "channel_counts": channel_counts}
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Guild not found")

def run_discord_bot():
    bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    discord_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_discord_bot)
    discord_process.start()

    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8001)
```